# Wrong type error when creating a table with symbols with spaces in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

I am trying to create a table of symbols in kdb, where the values of the table have spaces within. I have got

```
tab:([colOne:`$"value 1"`$"value 2"]colTwo:`$"value 3"`$"value 4")
```

currently, but this just returns

```
ERROR: `type (wrong type)
```

i have followed http://www.kdbfaq.com/kdb-faq/tag/sym-with-a-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
tab:([colOne:`$("value 1";"value 2")]colTwo:`$("value 3";"value 4"))
```

Remember that evaluation in q is left-to-right:

```
colTwo:`$"value 3"`$"value 4"
`$"value 4" will be evaluated to symbol
```

Then it will try to apply this symbol to what's on the left:

```
"value 3" `$"value 4"
```

which will give you `'type`

Comment: Could you please add an explanation?

Comment: helpful explanation, thanks.

I understand that the reason for `\`type`, so I was curious to try `(\`$"value 3")\`$"value 4"

this however gives an error as `\`value 3`. what is the explanation for this?

Comment: it tries to lookup function with a name of symbol on the left and call it with argument on the right. As you don't have function with name "value 3" defined - it tells you just that. `a:{show 123}; \`a \`b`

Answer (score 2):

you are right about sym with a space part but while creating a table columns take lists as inputs.

```
tab:([colOne:`a`b]colTwo:`c`d)
```

would be ok as `` `a`b `` is a list but when using syms with spaces you need to enclose them in `()` to make a list.

below will also work though sergey's answer is a better way of doing it.

```
tab:([colOne:(`$"value 1";`$"value 2")]colTwo:(`$"value 3";`$"value 4"))
```